# Caurina Tweener not finishing animation problem

Tags: actionscript-3, tweener

Hello
I am coding a website 
I am using caurina tweener and hove problem with pretty much every object that i try to tween.
Problem is that the tweened object sometimes just don't finish the animation. That's pretty annoying and i heard that this could be something with garbage collection.
Here is some sample code

```
Tweener.addTween(this, { rotationX:0, time:.5 } ); //Where 'this' is movieClip
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

since you're rotating your object in 3D (rotationX) it's more likely, as it seems, that your object is completing the tween correctly but your perspective makes it appear otherwise.

more here:  [Example: Perspective projection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSCE716DAD-9364-464f-AFE9-8E578525AD54.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have competing Tweens running at the same time.  This can result in conflicting animations, and the last one to run will be the only one you see.  I usually do a Tweener.removeTweens(myObject) prior to calling Tweener.addTween(myObject, {}):

```
Tweener.removeTweens(this);
Tweener.addTween(this, { rotationX:0, time:.5 } );
```